# What is the difference between JSON and AJAX with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cross-browser

I've heard that JSON serializes all the data, which stops me having problems client side in terms of cross-browser support etc..

I've been using AJAX with jQuery and it seems easy, but I'm unsure of the differences,

I've read I can also use this to get the data:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Can anyone explain the difference between making a jQuery AJAX request using JSON and making a jQuery AJAX request without the json type?

Will the answer be ok for all browsers?

Comment: Only use `dataType: 'json'` if the response should be interpreted as JSON. Using the `json` datatype for, say, html is not wise.

Comment: You get points for answers, Rob ;)

Comment: but what if i need to return an object? is basically the answer of a database consult... is it better to use json or only jquery?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you are confusing the terms.

AJAX stands for **A**synchronous **J**avascript **a**nd **X**ML, which is a mechanism used to launch asynchronous HTTP requests to a server using JavaScript. Don't let the name fool you; there's no restriction on you only retrieving JavaScript or XML from this technique. You can quite happily return other data formats as well (HTML, plain text and JSON, to list a few).

JSON is just one of these formats. It's a data interchange format, where-as AJAX is a technique to communicate with a server *after* the initate page load has completed.

To answer your question on whether you need to specify the `dataType`; jQuery will best guess the response format (be it HTML or JSON etc), so you're usually fine to omit it.

Answer (score 5):

The `dataType` option simply changes what type of data jquery should expect from the server. It can be `json`, `jsonp`, `html`, `text`, `xml`, or any custom datatype that you define a converter for. They all work in all browsers.

By default jQuery will try to detect what type of data is being returned if you do not supply a `dataType` option, however I find that it doesn't automatically detect very well.

Edit:

> but what if i need to return an object? is basically the answer of a database consult... is it better to use json or only jquery?

You can return an object in the form of `html`, `xml`, `json`, or `jsonp`. As long as it is in one of those formats, jQuery will be able to interpret it.

Answer (score 3):

**JQuery**: It is a light weight Javascript Library.

**JSON** - Stands for JavaScript Object Notation.

**Jquery**:It is created using JavaScript and you will be using the inbuilt functionalities from the library.

**Json:** JSON is a text format that is completely language independent.

**JQuery**:It is a fast and minified JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript.

**Json**: If you want assign data to Your grid then it is possible with Json.